# Allow IONIC DevApp through the firewall

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-devapp

I am able to connect to IONIC DEVAPP via my personal computer but unable to connect it when hosted on the office laptop even on my home wifi network.

I can see my app on both office and personal laptop.

```
$ionic serve -c
```

I am able to access the Devapp hosted URL via my browser

```
http://192.168.1.115:8100/?devapp=true
```

But, from my Android device, on my office laptop it gives the following error

> net::ERR:CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT( http://192.168.1.115:8100/?devapp=true)

It seems more like a Firewall Issue rather than a network issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to open the port in windows firewall, since you told that you're using windows...

- Go to Control Panel and find Windows Firewall.
- Click the Advanced Settings.
- On the left you must click Inbound Rules and under Actions, click the New Rule.
- Select Port.
- Type the ports you want to open.
- Allow the Connection and configure the rest.

Done;

Add this line to your config.xml file:

```
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```

Now test your DevApp again.
You can use Android Emulator on your device instead if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and thought as you did, that this was a firewall issue. As I am on Ubuntu, using the `ufw` firewall...

```
sudo ufw allow 8100
```

in a terminal did the trick for me, and `IONIC DEVAPP` connected to my app.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But, i am a Windows User. Any idea how to do it on Windows.